# How to open a new tab on button click

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, tabnavigator

I have a tab navigator which contains the 4 tabs Account, Configuration, System and Dashboard. In the Configuration tab there is a button labeled `add new config`. If the user clicks this button the system tab should open - how to do this?

Comment: Will you provide some code that you had done so far.. so that we can get idea that what you want to do.

Comment: actually other codes are done in two pages
i just want to open that system tab for the " set new config" button on congifuration tab..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<mx1:TabNavigator width="50%" height="50%" id="tabnav">

    <mx1:VBox label="Account" width="20%" height="20%">

    </mx1:VBox>
    <mx1:VBox label="Configuration" width="20%" height="20%">
        <s:Button id="c" click="c_clickHandler(event)" label="new config"/>
    </mx1:VBox>
    <mx1:VBox label="System" width="20%" height="20%">

    </mx1:VBox>
    <mx1:VBox label="Dash board" width="20%" height="20%">

    </mx1:VBox>

</mx1:TabNavigator>


protected function c_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
   {
     tabnav.selectedIndex = 2;
   }
```

Comment: in my project i already took a view stack and a button bar
in the button bar there are Account,Configuration,System and dashboard
so i want to redirect to sytem tab when the users click the button "set new config" in configuration tab
so the above example wont wrk for button bar

Comment: @aritra above example is good enough to dynamically select tab in tab navigator. If you want something else than this.. show some code what you have tried and why it is not working?

Comment: just one query
i have the view stack in a package
where as all components (configuration,account,dashboard,system) mxmls are in differet package
how to call that view stack by id??
i tried flexglobal.toplevelapplication
is not working

Comment: use each component as array in viewstack and select index of view stack when u need.